# How the prove that the equality in the triangle inequality holds only if $z = tw$ or $w = cz$ for some $t,c \in \mathbb{R}^{nn}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In the book of *Functions of One Complex Variable* by Conway, at page 3, it is stated that

> [...] On encountering an inequality one should always ask for
>   necessary and sufficient conditions that equality obtains. From
>   looking at a triangle and considering the geometrical significance of 
>   $$|z + w| \leq (|z| + |w|) \quad (z,w \in \mathbb{C}),$$ we are led to
>   consider the condition $z = tw$ for some $t\in \mathbb{R}^{nn}$. [...]

Even though the author does not give an explicit proof for the fact that when equality holds in the triangle inequality for two complex numbers, then one of the complex numbers should be a multiple of the other; I have tried to prove this; even though I can show that what the author claims is true, I couldn't show that that is the only case where the equality hold.Here is what I have done;

### Solution:

I have directly written $z = a + bi$, and $w = p+ qi$, and explicitly computed both parts of the equality, and in the end got

$$2abpq = (aq)^2 + (bp)^2,$$
i.e whenever the equality holds, this above must also hold.

It is clear that if $z = tw$ or $w = cz$ for some $t,c \in \mathbb{R}^{nn}$, then the above equality holds.

**However, I would like to this is the only case where the inequality holds, so how can we do that ?**

Comment: Have you considered the *geometrical significance* as the author advises?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, but I would also like to prove it rigorously also.

Answer (score 1):

$|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ implies $|z|^{2}+|w|^{2} +2 Re (z\overset {-} w)=|z|^{2}+|w|^{2}+2|z||w|$, so $Re (z\overset {-} w)=|z||w|$. Now let $t \geq 0$ and  consider $|z-tw|^{2}=|z|^{2}+t^{2}|w|^{2}-2t  Re (z\overset {-} w)=|z|^{2}+t^{2}|w|^{2}-2t |z||w|$. Choose $t$ such that the right side is $0$ and you will get $z=tw$. To find $t$ you just have to solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer and your effort to help me, but _as I have stated_ in my question, I have already shown that when $z = tw$ for some $t\geq 0$, we have the inequality.However, what I couldn't show is that this is the _only_ case where we can have an equality.

Comment: What I have proved is that if equality holds then we must have $z=tw$ for some $t \geq 0$. This is the converse of what you already stated and it says that equality does not hold in any other case.

Comment: Then if we were to assume that there is another solution that is not in that form, we should directly be able to show a contradiction by using what you just have proved ,but I do not see how can we do that. Can you explain how to do this ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Your confusion is not connected with the problem at hand but with logic. I hope someone else can explain the situation to you better. As far as I can see I have completely answered your question and I cannot make it clearer.

Comment: With all due respect sir, the complete proof of theorem saying "this equality has a solution of 'such' a form only", you need to take an arbitrary solution, and show that it is of the form $z = tw$. If you cannot state this in your answer by some means, your proof is not complete.

Comment: But still I appreciate the sentiment.